# Calculate the size of rendered QLabel

Tags: qt4, qlabel, qt4.8

I would like to render a complex rich-text QLabel content to a pixmap so I can animate that pixmap much smoother than rendering the QLabel every frame.

How do I know what size I should create pixmap. Is there way to ask QLabel what preferred bounding rect you need to render the content - unrestricted by any parent layout?

I tried QLabel::fontMetrics but of course that doesn't work for rich-text content. Is there anything else I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, calling QLabel::adjustSize() and retrieving the QLabel::size() works.

However, if the QLabel has no parent (i.e. it's considered a 'top level' widget), Qt will then restrict size of the widget to 2/3rds of the screen size. I was coming across this problem - I couldn't work out why the QLabel was always clipped to 1280 pixels (on a 1920x1080 screen).

But sizeHint() was always returning the correct size for the label.

In the end, I did:

```
label->adjustSize();
label->resize(label->sizeHint());

QPixmap pixmap(label->size());
label->render(&pixmap);
```

It's important to resize the label and not just set the pixmap to the label's sizeHint() because it could still be clipped.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by simply using `QPixmap::grabWidget(label)`; no size needed. See the docs for details.